# How to group by values based on common elements of the queryset in Django view?

Tags: python, django, view, nested, django-queryset

I'm new to Django and I need this data to render some chart please help
I must get my queryset as a dictionary in a specific structure

This is my view:

```
def pr1(request):
    fdate = unidecode(str(request.GET.get('fdate')))
    tdate = unidecode(str(request.GET.get('tdate')))                

    dataSource = OrderedDict()
    dataSource["dataset"] = []

    for key in Production.objects.filter(date__range=(fdate, tdate)).values('date', 'comName').annotate(total_qty=Sum('qty')):

        seriesname = {}
        data = {}        
        data["seriesname"]     = key['comName']
        data["value"]          = key['total_qty']
        dataSource["dataset"].append(data)
```

This is output of my query:

```
[
 {'date': '1398/08/01', 'comName': 'a', 'total_qty': 253.0}, 
 {'date': '1398/08/02', 'comName': 'a', 'total_qty': 263.0}, 
 {'date': '1398/08/01', 'comName': 'b', 'total_qty': 3.938}, 
 {'date': '1398/08/02', 'comName': 'b', 'total_qty': 31.625}
]
```

datasource after appending:

```
"dataset": [
  {
    "seriesname": "a",
    "value": 253
  },
  {
    "seriesname": "a",
    "value": 263
  },
  {
    "seriesname": "b",
    "value": 3.938
  },
  {
    "seriesname": "b",
    "value": 31.625
  }
```

but I have to get it as following:

```
"dataset": [
{
    "seriesname": "a",
    "data": [
        {
            "value": "253"
        },
        {
            "value": "263"
        }]},
        {
    "seriesname": "b",
    "data": [
        {
            "value": "3.938"
        },
        {
            "value": "31.625"
        }]}
        ]
```

Comment: Are you sure about the structure you want to get? Looks a bit strange - dictionaries with only one element?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What have you tried, exactly, what is the issue? Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @ger.s.brett i have simpilified my code. rest of my dictionary is fine, i just don't know how to get this part fixed

Comment: @AMC yes my question is how get my output as the desired one 
i have tried iteration but couldn't figure it out

Comment: @HadiWaheed Then share the code you tried, right? Stack Overflow is not meant for general "How do I do the thing" questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really a Django specific question but a general Python one. You could change your iteration, e.g.

```
def pr1(request):
    fdate = unidecode(str(request.GET.get('fdate')))
    tdate = unidecode(str(request.GET.get('tdate')))                

    dataSource = OrderedDict()
    dataSource["dataset"] = []

    seriesname = ''
    data = None

    for key in Production.objects.filter(date__range=(fdate, tdate)).values('date', 'comName').annotate(total_qty=Sum('qty')).order_by('comName':

        if not key['comName'] == seriesname:
            seriesname = key['comName']
            if data is not None:
                dataSource["dataset"].append(data)
            data = {
                'seriesname': key['comName'],
                'data': [
                    {'value': key['total_qty']}
                ]
            }
        else:
            data['data'].append({'value': key['total_qty']})

    dataSource["dataset"].append(data)
```

I added `order_by` to your queryset for this to work.